# shift operation with hexadecimal output

Tags: hex, bit-shift, shift

I have known till date that %x prints in hexadecimals

Now, when I write `printf("%x", -1<<4)`,the output is fffffff0

But when I write `printf("%x", 5<<2)`, the output is 14

Why does the second output a decimal number?

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: well, when i use %x, atleast the output should be in hexadecimal

Comment: But again, what result were you expecting?

Comment: @Ceres111 5<<2 == 20 == 0x14

Comment: Well, i ain't sure. I know how shift operations work. If I change my code as printf("%d", 5<<2), it gives 20 as 5*(2^2)=20... Now when I use %x, it gives 14 which is not understandable

Comment: @Dirk what do u mean by saying 20==0x14

Comment: @Ceres111 20 in decimal system is equal to 14 in hexadecimal system. They are the same value just using a different base.

Comment: @Dirk ok, i got that now... can u explain me the first result then i.e., -1<<4

Comment: @Ceres111 -1 is stored as ffffffff ([Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). Shifting it left by four bits puts 0s in the four least significant bits, whichs makes it fffffff0.

Answer (score 0):

14 is part of hexadecimal characters set, it's just the result of :

floor(20/16) and 20%16

Comment: well in hexadecimal set, i thought its 0-9 and A-F

Comment: @Ceres111 and both 1 and 4 are in the range 0-9.

Comment: @nfroidure ok, i got it... u mean its one four and not fourteen

Comment: then how -1<<4 resulted in fffffff0

Comment: it's probably the way negative numbers get encoded in your system. I assume that the sign is coded on one bit at the begin of the bit sequence representing your integer.

Comment: @nfroidure, do you know of literally any system in real use today that *doesn't* use two's complement?

Comment: @Cairnarvon not an arch expert ;)